# How to find the index of the string separated by delimeters in progress openedge 4gl?

Tags: string, indexing, progress-4gl, openedge

I want to find  the index of 56 in  "STS++5623+56+ 123 " . The code I have written  gives me 6 (of 5623)  but I need 11.

```
DEFINE var v-segment as longchar no-undo. 
DEFINE VARIABLE v-element AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
ASSIGN v-segment = "STS++5623+56".
ASSIGN v-element = "56".

define variable v-index as integer no-undo.

v-index = index(v-segment , v-element , 1).

MESSAGE v-index
     VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
```

Comment: Your title says "separated by delimiters".  But the body of the question does not indicate what the delimiters are and why they are important.  Nor do you explain why you are unhappy with 6 and what makes 11 a better answer.  One way to interpret your need is that you want the 2nd instance of "56" rather than the first.  But I suspect that the reality is more complex than that.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry the previous answer wasn't what you needed.  I decided to leave it up, because it is a nice solution to the problem as stated.  But I'll try again.  I made the check for delimiters a separate function so you can easily adapt it to your requirements.  Adding multi-byte character capabilities should be straightforward.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE v-segment    AS LONGCHAR  NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE v-element    AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE v-delims     AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

DEFINE VARIABLE v-index      AS INTEGER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE v-delimCount AS INTEGER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE v-segLength  AS INTEGER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE v-eltLength  AS INTEGER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE v-psn        AS INTEGER   NO-UNDO.

ASSIGN v-segment    = "STS++5623+56"
       v-element    = "56"
       v-delims     = "+:"
       /* For efficiency, don't calculate these inside your loop */
       v-seglength  = LENGTH( v-segment)
       v-eltLength  = LENGTH( v-element)
       v-delimCount = LENGTH( v-delims).


/*
** isDelin()
** Is character at specified positiion one of the delimiters?
**
**   Params:
**   CHARACTER p-str    - string to search
**   INTEGER   p-psn    - position to check
**   CHARACTER p-delims - list of delimiters to check for
**
** Returns TRUE if character at specified position is a delimiter
** Otherwise, returns FALSE
*/
FUNCTION isDelim RETURNS LOGICAL (
  INPUT p-str     AS LONGCHAR,
  INPUT p-psn     AS INTEGER,
  INPUT p-delims  AS CHARACTER
):

  /* You might want parameter checking here.... */
  RETURN INDEX( p-delims, SUBSTRING( p-str, p-psn, 1)) > 0.

END FUNCTION.  /* isDelim */

/*
** You might want special case handling here:
**   if v-eltLength = 0 then v-index = 1.  return.
**   IF v-element = ? or v-segment = ? then v-index = 0.  return.
*/

/* Look for v-element, then see if it is surrounded by delimiters */
v-index = 0.
DO WHILE TRUE:

  v-index = INDEX( v-segment, v-element, v-index + 1).
  If v-index = 0 THEN LEAVE.   /* No more matches */

  /*
  ** Found a match.  Is it preceded by a delimiter?
  ** (Don't check if match is at beginning of string.)
  */
  v-psn = v-index - 1.
  IF v-psn > 0 AND NOT isDelim( v-segment, v-psn, v-delims) THEN NEXT.

  /*
  ** Is match followed by a delimiter?
  ** (Don't check if match is at end of string.)
  */
  v-psn = v-index + v-eltLength.
  IF v-psn > v-seglength THEN LEAVE.

  IF NOT isDelim(v-segment, v-psn, v-delims) THEN NEXT.

  /* Success! */
  LEAVE.
END.

MESSAGE v-index VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
```

Comment: Thanks , exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Glad to hear it.  You should check off the answer to mark this one solved; that will make it easier for future searches to locate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
DEFINE var v-segment as longchar no-undo.
DEFINE VARIABLE v-element AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
def var v-i as int no-undo.
def var v-data as char no-undo.

ASSIGN v-segment = "STS++5623+56+123".
ASSIGN v-element = "56".

define variable v-index as integer no-undo.

do v-i = 1 to num-entries(v-segment,"+"):

   if entry(v-i,v-segment,"+") = v-element then
  do:

     v-data = entry(v-i,v-segment,"+").

     MESSAGE v-data VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.

     end.

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to approach this.  Which is smartest depends upon the data.  I can think of two that do not involve loops, which may be what you are looking for.  I haven't done any benchmarking, but I think the code below would is the most efficient algorithm.  At most it involves three string searches -- one `entry()`, one `num-entries()`, and one `index()`.  If this doesn't meet your needs, I can suggest alternatives.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE v-segment AS LONGCHAR  NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE v-element AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE v-index   AS INTEGER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE v-entry   AS INTEGER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE v-delim   AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

ASSIGN v-segment = "STS++5623+56"
       v-element = "56"
       v-delim   = "+".

/* Does the segment contain the exact entry? */
v-entry = LOOKUP(v-element, v-segment, v-delim).

/*
** If entry number = 0, then element is not found
** If entry number = 1, then element is at beginning of segment.
** If entry number = num-entries(), then element is at end of segment
** Otherwise, element is in the middle; just search for it surrounded
**    by delimters.
*/

IF v-entry = 0 THEN
  v-index = 0.
ELSE IF v-entry = 1 THEN 
  v-index = 1.
ELSE IF v-entry = NUM-ENTRIES( v-segment, v-delim) THEN  
  v-index = R-INDEX( v-segment, v-delim) + 1.
else                                                     
  v-index = INDEX( v-segment, v-delim + v-element + v-delim) + 1.

MESSAGE v-index VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
```

Comment: This does not work for "STS++5623+::56"  , : is another delimiter . I forgot to mention : can be another possible delimiter ,

Comment: Any other important facets to the problem?  In particular:  are all the delimiters single characters?

Comment: Also: Do you need a solution that supports multi-byte characters, like UTF-8?